# Css style <ul> not working properly

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I really cant figure out why the images on my `<ul>` wont work.

I need to style the ul with a class but the `<li>` keeps looking the same. 
Here is my css code:

```
body{padding:0;margin:0;  background:#39424b; font-family: verdana;}
h1, h2{padding:0;margin:10px 0 10px 0;}
h1 {font-size: 150%;}
h2 {font-size: 110%;}
p{padding:0; margin:0 0 5px 0;}
a {color:#176092; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
#wrap {width:960px; margin: 0 auto; background:#999;}
#header, #footer {background: #0f1923; color:#fff; padding:10px 40px;}
#footer p {font-size:80%; text-align:right;}
#content {background:#ccc; padding:10px 40px;}
pre {font-size:85%; background:#fff; border:1px #ccc solid; padding:5px}
#checkjul ul {
list-style-image: url('http://dorchdanola-netbutik.dk/Resources/Files/general/checkbox-jul.png');
padding-left: 25px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
height: 19px;
}

#slide-out-div-jule-holder {
width: 600px;
height: 270px;
margin: 20px;
margin-top: 10px;
```

Here is my html code:

```
 <div class="slide-out-div">
        <a class="handle" href="http://link-for-non-js-users">Julehandel</a>
        <div style="float:left" class="slide-out-div-jule-holder">
       <b>K&oslash;b julegaver hos Dorch & Danola<br /> - Nemt, Sikkert og billigt!</b>
       <ul class="checkjul"><li>E-m&aelig;rket kontrolleret webshop for sikker handel</li>
      <li>Vi bytter alle ordre k&oslash;bt fra 20. oktober frem til og med den 15. januar 2015</li> 
        <li>Gratis ombytning af Julegaver - Vi sender returlabel </li>
       <li> Sidste bestillingsdato for julegaver er den 22. december.</li>
       <li> Hurtig levering - Fragt fra Kr. 39,-</li> 
      <b>Dorch & Danola &oslash;nsker alle en gl&aelig;delig jul og et rigtig godt nyt&aring;</b></ul>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: How is that related to javascript/jQuery???

Comment: @A.Wolff good call, I posted an edit to remove those tags.

Answer (score 1):

So it doesn't work because you are styling #checkjul ul but you don't have such an element. So to work you need to add those styles to your ul class .checkjul and it will work :)

```css
 body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background: #39424b;
   font-family: verdana;
 }
 h1,
 h2 {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
 }
 h1 {
   font-size: 150%;
 }
 h2 {
   font-size: 110%;
 }
 p {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0 0 5px 0;
 }
 a {
   color: #176092;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 a:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
 }
 #wrap {
   width: 960px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background: #999;
 }
 #header,
 #footer {
   background: #0f1923;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 10px 40px;
 }
 #footer p {
   font-size: 80%;
   text-align: right;
 }
 #content {
   background: #ccc;
   padding: 10px 40px;
 }
 pre {
   font-size: 85%;
   background: #fff;
   border: 1px #ccc solid;
   padding: 5px
 }
 .checkjul{
   list-style-image: url('http://dorchdanola-netbutik.dk/Resources/Files/general/checkbox-jul.png');
   padding-left: 25px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   height: 19px;
 }
 #slide-out-div-jule-holder {
   width: 600px;
   height: 270px;
   margin: 20px;
   margin-top: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="slide-out-div">
  <a class="handle" href="http://link-for-non-js-users">Julehandel</a>
  <div style="float:left" class="slide-out-div-jule-holder">
    <b>K&oslash;b julegaver hos Dorch & Danola<br /> - Nemt, Sikkert og billigt!</b>
    
    <ul class="checkjul">
      <li>E-m&aelig;rket kontrolleret webshop for sikker handel</li>
      <li>Vi bytter alle ordre k&oslash;bt fra 20. oktober frem til og med den 15. januar 2015</li>
      <li>Gratis ombytning af Julegaver - Vi sender returlabel</li>
      <li>Sidste bestillingsdato for julegaver er den 22. december.</li>
      <li>Hurtig levering - Fragt fra Kr. 39,-</li>
      <b>Dorch & Danola &oslash;nsker alle en gl&aelig;delig jul og et rigtig godt nyt&aring;</b>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
<ul class="checkjul">
```

but you are defining your style as an ID, and applying it to the wrong element:

```
#checkjul ul
```

For this to work, you will need:

```
.checkjul li
```

Comment: Thanks I got it fixed! :D ..

But somehow my url is not aligned to the text they are really jumping around, is there away to fix it with space or something like it?

Comment: Hi guys, Now my code looks like this: 
`  .slide-out-div {
       padding: 20px;
        width: 450px;
        height: 170px;
        background: #f2f2f2;
        border: #29216d 2px solid;    
    }
    

p{padding:0; margin:0 0 5px 0;}

.slide-out-div-jule-holder ul  {
    list-style-image: url(http://dorchdanola-netbutik.dk/Resources/Files/general/checkbox-jul.png);
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height:19px;
}


#slide-out-div-jule-holder {
width: 600px;
height: 270px;
margin: 20px;
margin-top: 10px;
}

</style>`

Somehow the height om my image ul is not adjusting.